# Example of an bounded , self-inverse, anti-multiplicative, anti-linear operator on banach algebra

Tags: c-star-algebras

Actually I want an involution on Banach algebra B such that

- ||x*|| $\le$ c.||x|| $\forall$ x in B and some c > 1
- $\exists$ y in B such that ||y*|| $\ne$ ||y||

Comment: But, $y^{**}=y$, so $\|y\|\le c\|y^*\|$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: But I want such kind of involution which is not isometry.    (i) $\frac{1}{c}$.||x|| $\le$ ||x*|| $\le$ c.||x|| $\forall$ x in B and some c > 1( for continuity of involution ).   (ii) $\exists$ y in B such that ||y*|| $\neq$ ||y|| ( for non-isometry )